# Finding unitary rotation matrix for triangularization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices, triangularization

I have an arbitrary complex $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ and want to find a unitary rotation

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
       c & -\bar{s} \\
       s &  \bar{c} \\
      \end{bmatrix}$$

with $|c|^2+|s|^2 = 1$, such that

$$Q^HB = \begin{bmatrix}
          f & z_1 \\
          0 & z_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

where $f$ is a real number and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers.

This is to triangularize $B$ as it is described in this paper:
[Computing the Singular Values of 2-by-2 Complex
Matrices](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~qiao/publications/zsvd2.ps).

Comment: What you're looking for is a [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $B$.

Comment: Try the [Givens rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation). BTW your $Q$ is not unitary (I guess you made a typo). Also, I believe you meant the conjugate transpose ($^H$) instead of the ordinary transposition ($^T$).

Comment: You're right. I edited the question. In the paper, $Q$ is called a unitary rotation, but it's of course not a unitary matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the *notation used in the linked paper*,
$$
c=\frac{b_{11}}{f}, \quad s=\frac{b_{12}}{f}, \quad f=\sqrt{|b_{11}|^2+|b_{12}|^2},
$$
where $\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}\\b_{12}\end{bmatrix}$ is the first column of $B$.
It is trivial to verify that
$$
Q^H\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}\\b_{12}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\overline{c}&\overline{s}\\-s &c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}\\b_{12}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}f\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$